# SQL Не выводит инфо о таблице

Tags: sql

Занимаюсь sql по литературе. Требовалось задать столбцы таблицы и вывести инфо о ней следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE my_contacts(
last_name VARCHAR(30),
first_name VARCHAR(20),
email VARCHAR(50),
gender CHAR(1),
birthday DATE,
status VARCHAR(20)
);
        
DESC my_contacts;
```

Инфо не выводит,но выводит след.ошибку:
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "DESC")
LINE 10: DESC my_contacts;
^
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: А какая база данных и через что вы отправляете запрос ? получение структуры таблиц у каждой БД делается по своему. И часто команды вроде desc вообще обеспечиваются не БД, а средствами работы с ними через которые передаются команды

Comment: Извините,забыла указать.Работаю в PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Команды ввожу через запросник. (ПКМ по БД->запросник)

Comment: postgresql не поддерживает команду desc. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table/

Comment: Поняла.Спасибо большое!